# How to fix "address space is already occupied" error on fetch/commit?

Tags: git, cygwin

Started recently, basically every time I try to fetch or commit it gives me this weird error. It'll continuously try to "refetch/recommit" until I give up and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

```
C:\cygwin\home\git\new_trunk>git sf
      1 [main] perl 760 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'cygreadline7.dll' (0x960000) is already occupied

C:\cygwin\home\git\new_trunk>git svn dcommit
      1 [main] perl 2672 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'cygreadline7.dll' (0x980000) is already occupied
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Something is wrong with your cygwin install As an alternative, you could use the [official git build](http://git-scm.com/downloads) (which uses msys) instead.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen probable, i did update cygwin with some other stuff. will try

Comment: Had the same problem while using Git Bash spawned from SourceTree in Windows for command `git add -p`. This doesn't occur when Git Bash is opened from the Explorer context menu.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at [this Cygwin FAQ section](http://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.using.fixing-fork-failures) and [this too](http://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.using.bloda).
In my case, disabling Avast's Behavior and Filesystem Realtime shields and
then restarting Cygwin was the answer.

So, probably, you are running windows programs that hooks their DLLs into
forked processes, disrupting addresses and thus causing fork to malfunction.

Comment: I think I experienced similar behavior with Microsoft Security Essentials.

Comment: Confirming this problem with Sophos' Behavior Monitoring - uncheck behavior monitoring, restart cygwin.

Comment: I my case it was Windows 10's Virus & Threat Protection causing the problem.

Comment: @Koning what about W10's virus settings did you change to fix it?

Comment: I turned off everything including real-time protection.

Answer (score 33):

Rebasing my Cygwin install solved this for me. I followed the doc [Rebaseall](http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/Rebaseall), running dash as admin from Windows Explorer and then issuing the following:

```
/usr/bin/rebaseall -v
```

P.S.: No Cygwin service should be running for this to work.

Comment: This was a temporary solution for me. Fixed the problem for few hours only.

Comment: Tip: ash is usually found in cygwin installation dir:

C:\cygwin\bin\ash.exe

Comment: As for "No Cygwin service should be running for this to work.", I had the same problem with Msys2, and even after closing all terminals I had to kill `ssh-pageant` via Task Manager.

Answer (score 7):

I had this same fork() problem when my virus scanner, Symantec Endpoint Protection, was upgraded to 64-bit, but I was still running the 32-bit version of Cygwin.  'Rebaseall' didn't help. Upgrading to the 64-bit version of Cygwin has fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I had similar issues; was having this error doing a [git difftool -dirdiff] and hadn't recognised that a new version of SEP (32bit) was installed and asking to be rebooted to complete installation.  Problem went away after rebooting and SEP was completely installed.

Comment: I had a similar issue trying to use git svn to clone a repo.  It endlessly reported that mysqlite.dll was already in a given memory location.   The command line in mingw32 was something like "C:\Program Files (x86)\git\git.exe" svn clone .....  anyway the exe was wrapped in dquotes.  So I scraped out the command and changed it to just say  
 svn git clone  ..... and MAGIC - it runs.  So apparently the use of the fully qualified EXE name in the shell was invoking a second copy of git.exe that attempted to lay itself into the same memory area or somesuch rather than running in its own space

Answer (score 2):

As [mentioned by Tarc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24414798/2707864), no Cygwin services should be running to `rebaseall`.
Otherwise you get

https://superuser.com/questions/231590/running-rebaseall-on-cygwin

Even after seemingly closing all Cygwin/Msys2 instances, you may find problems, as [I did](https://superuser.com/a/1364535/245595).
Using Win 10 and Msys2 from PortableApps, I went to Task Manager, I sorted the list by the column "Command line". There I found my ssh-agent from Msys2 still running.
I killed it, and then I could `rebaseall` .